# 422 [Error] Cannot Process In CloudWatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to make a Lambda hit a HTTP endpoint and deliver some simple JSON  - Lambda works completely fine and the URL is ok however when the JSON is trying to be delivered I see a 422 error [Error Cannot Process] when I check CloudWatch Logs.  Any idea why this could be?

Comment: You need to provide more details than that. Example lambda code, full error message, details of lambda setup (e.g. is it integrated with a VPC)?

Comment: Marcin is correct; you need to provide a lot more detail. I just want to add that you could try doing the same request using a local HTTP client such as [Postman API Client](https://www.postman.com/product/api-client/) to make sure that you're sending the correct JSON to the server. Feel free to let me know once you've updated the question and I'd be happy to have a look.